# Why does the R leaflet documenatation recommend making a new function for color palette?

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

Much of the documentation for R leaflet's color palette function suggests creating a new function (usually `pal()`. See, for example,:

- the last example at https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html
- most of the examples at https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/colors.html
- the built-in examples for the palette functions (https://rdrr.io/cran/leaflet/man/colorNumeric.html)

I understand how to create a regular function in R and pass arguments to it, but I don't understand what's going on in these examples. It seems like the new `pal()` function doesn't have any arguments (or all the defaults are already passed to it when it's created?), but when you use it in a map, it's typically passed an argument that determines the actual value/color to be displayed.

What's actually going on here and why shouldn't I just put the original function in the map argument?

Comment: Taking the first example linked, they assign `colorFactor` to `pal()`. If you type `colorFactor` and look at the underlying function, it does take a parameter (argument). I believe the reason they assign it to `pal()` is that they first specified 2 different states/colors, then let that vary based on `type`. You can pass `type` to `pal()` but I don't think think you could pass that directly into `colorFactor`.

Comment: Have you tried putting in the original function into the map argument? the [source code](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/blob/36a9ee3bae4ef246a2ec7ba48f966bdea8183286/R/colors.R) is a good place to look at what's going on

Comment: I tried passing the original function into the map--it didn't give me the output I expected. So I read the source code--that's when I realized I have no idea what's happening! Where does the columnname argument that gets passed into `~pal(columnname`) when you're building a map go? It seems like it ought to get passed to the palette argument of `colorBin()` or whatever, but that doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: I've thought about this a bit...Maybe the issue is that I don't understand the arguments of the original function, ie. what a "domain" is or how it works (or the other arguments either)?